# How to perform validation in JSF, how to create a custom validator in JSF

Tags: validation, jsf

I would like to perform validation in some of my input components such as `<h:inputText>` using some Java bean method. Should I use `<f:validator>` or `<f:validateBean>` for this? Where can I read more about it?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The standard way is to implement the [`Validator`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/10/apidocs/jakarta/faces/validator/validator) interface.

```java
@FacesValidator("fooValidator")
public class FooValidator implements Validator<String> {

    @Override
    public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) throws ValidatorException {
        if (value == null || value.isEmpty()) {
            // Let required="true" handle it.
        }

        // ...

        if (valueIsInvalid) {
            throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage("Value is invalid!"));
        }
    }
}
```

The `component` argument represents the component to which the validator is attached, which is usually an instance of [`UIInput`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/10/apidocs/jakarta/faces/component/uiinput). The `value` argument represents the value to be validated, which is usually the submitted and converted value of the associated `UIInput` component.

The [`@FacesValidator`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/10/apidocs/jakarta/faces/validator/facesvalidator) will register it to JSF with validator ID `myValidator` so that you can reference it in `validator` attribute of any `<h:inputXxx>`/`<h:selectXxx>` component as follows:

```xml
<h:inputText id="foo" value="#{bean.foo}" validator="fooValidator" />
<h:message for="foo" />
```

If you consider the `value` invalid, then just throw `ValidatorException`. This way the input field will be marked invalid (i.e. `UIInput#isValid()` will return `false`), and the bean property behind the `value` attribute of the input field (the `#{bean.foo}`) won't be updated with the submitted/converted value, and the message of the `ValidatorException` will be displayed in the `<h:message>` associated with the input field.

Do note that checking for null/blank value should be delegated to the `required="true"` attribute like so:

```
<h:inputText id="foo" value="#{bean.foo}" validator="fooValidator"
    required="true" requiredMessage="Please fill out foo" />
<h:message for="foo" />
```

You can also use EL in `validator` attribute of any `<h:inputXxx>`/`<h:selectXxx>` component wherein you reference a managed bean method having exactly the same method signature (the same method arguments) as `Validator#validate()`. I.e. taking `FacesContext`, `UIComponent` and `Object` arguments in this order.

```xml
<h:inputText id="foo" value="#{bean.foo}" validator="#{bean.validateFoo}" />
<h:message for="foo" />
```

```java
public void validateFoo(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) throws ValidatorException {
    if (value == null || value.isEmpty()) {
        // Let required="true" handle it.
    }

    // ...

    if (valueIsInvalid) {
        throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage("Value is invalid!"));
    }
}
```

This is only useful if the validator needs to access another property present in the same managed bean. If it doesn't need to, then this approach is considered tight-coupling (poor practice thus), and you should split out the validator to its own class implementing the `Validator` interface.

In case you wish to validate based on multiple input values and/or bean properties, much better is to pass them as `<f:attribute>` of the component. More detail can be found in the answer to [JSF doesn't support cross-field validation, is there a workaround?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282466/jsf-doesnt-support-cross-field-validation-is-there-a-workaround)

You can also use `<f:validator>` taghandler, which would be the only way if you intend to attach multiple validators on the same component:

```xml
<h:inputText id="foo" value="#{bean.foo}">
    <f:validator validatorId="fooValidator" />
</h:inputText>
<h:message for="foo" />
```

This will execute the `@FacesValidator("fooValidator")` shown above.

You can also use `<f:validator binding>` to reference a concrete validator instance somewhere in the EL scope, which can be specified and supplied the following way:

```xml
<h:inputText id="foo" value="#{bean.foo}">
    <f:validator binding="#{fooValidator}" />
</h:inputText>
<h:message for="foo" />
```

```java
@Named("fooValidator")
public class FooValidator implements Validator<String> {

    @Override
    public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) throws ValidatorException {
        if (value == null || value.isEmpty()) {
            // Let required="true" handle it.
        }

        // ...

        if (valueIsInvalid) {
            throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage("Value is invalid!"));
        }
    }
}
```

Note that thus `@Named` is being used instead of `@FacesValidator`. The old `@ManagedBean` is also supported here instead of `@Named`. Historically, this was a trick in order to be able to use `@EJB` and `@Inject` in a validator. See also [How to inject in @FacesValidator with @EJB, @PersistenceContext, @Inject, @Autowired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7572335/how-to-inject-in-facesvalidator-with-ejb-persistencecontext-inject-autow)

Or this way, which in turn can easily be supplied as a lambda:

```xml
<h:inputText id="foo" value="#{bean.foo}">
    <f:validator binding="#{bean.fooValidator}" />
</h:inputText>
<h:message for="foo" />
```

```java
public Validator<String> getFooValidator() {
    return (context, component, value) -> {
        if (value == null || value.isEmpty()) {
            // Let required="true" handle it.
        }

        // ...

        if (valueIsInvalid) {
            throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage("Value is invalid!"));
        }
    };
}
```

Also here applies the same problem of tight-coupling when this validator doesn't need any other property from the same bean.

To get a step further, you can use JSR303 bean validation. This validates fields based on annotations. So you can have just a

```java
@Foo
private String foo;
```

Without the need to explicitly register any validator in XHTML side. If you're using JPA for persistence, by default this validator will also be executed during insert/update in DB. Since it's going to be a whole story, here are just some links to get started:

- [Hibernate Validator - Getting started](https://hibernate.org/validator/documentation/getting-started/)
- [JSF 2.0 tutorial - Finetuning validation](https://balusc.omnifaces.org/2011/01/jsf-20-tutorial-with-eclipse-and.html#FinetuningValidation)
- [How to perform JSF validation in actionListener or action method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5892225/jsf-2-0-validation-in-actionlistener-or-action-method)

There's also a `<f:validateBean>` tag, but this is only useful if you intend to **disable** the JSR303 bean validation. You then put the input components (or even the whole form) inside `<f:validateBean disabled="true">`.