# Localize Bean Validation messages in JSF app based on a property - I've only 1 file with a key for English and another key for Spanish

Tags: jsf, localization, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

`ValidationMessages.properties`

```
error.name.invalid= Inavlid name
error.name.invalid.spanish= some spanish text
```

How to use the Spanish validation message instead of English just for a single page in the application based on a property value?

Comment: Really? Why don't you use 1 file for English and 1 file for Spanish, both with identical keys, so that you can use the builtin localization facility, as recommended and demonstrated in the documentation and tutorials?

Answer (score 0):

If you really would like to do this, you could create custom validators. For example:

```
@FacesValidator("yourValidator")
public class YourValidator implements Validator
{

  @Override
  public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value)
  throws ValidatorException
  {
    ResourceBundle resourceBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("/ValidationMessages");
    String key = yourKey + (yourProperty ? "" : ".spanish");
    String message = resourceBundle.getString(key);
    FacesMessage facesMessage = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, message, message);
    throw new ValidatorException(facesMessage);
  }

}
```

See also:

- [How to perform validation in JSF, how to create a custom validator in JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6047866/how-to-perform-validation-in-jsf-how-to-create-a-custom-validator-in-jsf)

Comment: Custom validator might not be a good option. We have to write 10 or more custom validators for each field instead of a field level hibernate validator.

Comment: Of course it's a lot of work. The prefered way of handling this is having a separate message bundle for Spanish as @BalusC already pointed out.