# calender tag in jsf with date & time restriction

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

I have a jsf page named as page.xhtml like following:

```
<p:calendar id="start_date_time_label" widgetVar="myCalendar1"
    value="#{bean.startDateTime}" pattern="dd/MM/yy"
    style="width: 359px; " required="true"
    requiredMessage="Start Date is mandatory" />
```

Here I have added one javascript function like following to restrict the minimum date value:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            myCalendar1.jqEl.datepicker("option", "minDate", -365);//set minDate to 1 year back 
        });     
</script>
```

Till now the script is working fine.

Now as per requirement I have to change the pattern of p:calender tag to **pattern="dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss"**. But then the script is not working. Please help me to make it work with the time value.

Comment: Why don't you use a JSF validator? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6047866/how-to-perform-validation-in-jsf-how-to-create-a-custom-validator-in-jsf

Comment: @JasperdeVries: since using the minDate prevents you selecting it in the UI (but I'd prefer the PrimeFaces `minDate` calendar attribute then which OP could have found in the docs, showcase, IDE code completion and google)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use primefaces' mindate attribute?

```
<p:calendar id="start_date" mindate="#{of:addMonths(now, -12)}" value="#{bean.startDateTime}" pattern="dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss" />
```

The 1 year back minimum date is set via a combination of omnifaces' [now](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/managedbeans/now) bean and their [el date functions](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/functions/Dates), but you could replace it with a bean method that returns the same thing.

Comment: Does it work when using the mentioned pattern? I got the impression it worked with a pattern without the time but fails (in OP's case) with the time added. Can you explicitly test that? And personnaly, although this `mindate="#{of:addMonths(now, -12)}"` works, I'd put it in the model/backingbean like you suggest. Since it is less a UI/View thing (I think)

Comment: I've just tested the code and i couldn't see any glaring problems. I agree with using a backing bean as a means of consolidating the business logic nature of the > 1 year in the past requirement. That said, i love using omnifaces and its perfect for this quick demo! :)

Comment: Ok... And OmniFaces is perfect for waaaay more than just a quick demo (but it indeed saves code here ;-))