# How to validate a proper URL format using Java? I am having trouble understanding the logic

Tags: java, validation

There are 5 main parts to a proper URL link and the link is usually in the following format:  `http://<host>:<port>/<path>?<searchpart>` , but how to implement it into validation? I am just learning for my class and I can't seem to figure out, please be kind to explain

Comment: I am assuming you are passing url as input to a field in JSF. If that's the case then verify it on your backend java class if not valid render a error message

Comment: And see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6047866/how-to-perform-validation-in-jsf-how-to-create-a-custom-validator-in-jsf

Comment: Write a custom JSF validator that will verify that the input is a proper http link (url). Show the code.