# How to set a p:calendar invalid from the bean?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I tried to set a calendar as invalid from the Java bean. The code is:

```java
HtmlInputText htmlInput = (HtmlInputText) elem;
String classes = htmlInput.getStyleClass();
String newClasses = classes + " ui-state-error";
htmlInput.setStyleClass(newClasses);

UIInput input = (UIInput) elem;
input.setValid(false);
```

`elem` is the calendar. The class is ***NOT*** displayed in the browser inspector.

In theory, `input.setValid(false);` should be sufficient... Maybe the JS of `p:calendar` is doing something wrong?

The element is:

```html
<p:calendar 
    value="#{bean.val}"
    id="x"
    locale="it"
    showOtherMonths="true"
    pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"
    navigator="true" 
/>
```

I use Primefaces 3.4.1 with Mojarra 2.1.7

Comment: Did you update the component or a parent?

Comment: @JasperdeVries When the validation is finished, the whole form is updated. So, a parent.

Comment: Why do it the hard way by the way? Can't you just create a validator?

Comment: A Validator seemed to me more complicated :D but now that you rememberd me it, I'll try and I'll return with feedback

Comment: @JasperdeVries: well, it works, but no error message is displayed, even if I specified it in the `ValidatorException` constructor. Usually I have to problem to show messages with `addMessage`.

Comment: @JasperdeVries: mmmmmhhh.... clicking more times, I discovered that the message is created, but hidden immediately! How is it possible? With "addMessage", messages are shown as usual for some seconds.... But even if I pu an addMessage inside the `validate`, it's behaviour is the same!

Comment: That's a different question, which is hard to answer without much context.

Comment: Ok, I'll open another question. Can you answer to this question? I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try to reinvent the wheel. Instead, create a validator. It will take care of setting the valid state of the component, the error message and it is reusable.

See:

- [How to perform validation in JSF, how to create a custom validator in JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6047866/how-to-perform-validation-in-jsf-how-to-create-a-custom-validator-in-jsf)