# Specific error message does not render in Primefaces?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I would like to show specific error message.
Here is my form.

```
<h:form id="userEntryForm">
    <p:message for="email" styleClass="error-message"/>
    <p:inputText value="#{UserActionBean.user.email}" required="true" id="email" />                                         
</h:form>
```

When I use one parameter FacesMessage constructor as following,

```
 public boolean isValid() {
    if(...) {
        FacesMessage facesMessage = new FacesMessage("Error : Email does not match.")
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("entryForm:newPassword", facesMessage);
    }
 }
```

error message shows properly with info style css. I want to show error style so that I used
three parameter FacesMessage constructor,

```
FacesMessage facesMessage = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Error : Email does not match.", "")
```

error sign appears but does not render error message as follow.[image]

what is going wrong? thanks in advance.

Comment: You should use a normal validator. Check the bottom example of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5892225/jsf-2-0-validation-in-actionlistener-or-action-method/5897183#5897183

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both `h:message` and `p:message` show the detailed information per default. You can either put your message as third parameter of your `FacesMessage` or you add `showSummary="true"` and `showDetail="false"` to your `p:message` tag.