# How to make a form field conditionally required in JSF?

Tags: validation, jsf

Suppose I have an `h:form` with three fields and two submit buttons.  The submit buttons are, say, **Display Report** and **Generate Data**. For the simplicity, I would prefer to have only one and not multiple forms.  When **Display Report**, the values from the three fields are required as criteria for the report presentation.  So I marked them as `required="true"` but that disables the execution of **Generate Data**, which does not need those three fields.

Is there a way to make JSF form fields conditionally required without much custom coding, something like `requiredIf=#{condition}`?

Comment: Have you tried your suggestion ? `required=#{condition}` will works

Comment: can you put the code at pastebin?

Comment: in principle is just what you said... just put some " " or ' ', for correctness.

Comment: Depending upon your need, you can make an EL in the `required` attribute return a boolean value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If **Generate Data** action does not require any conversion or validation of form data then set the attribute `immediate` to `true` for this button:

```
<h:commandButton action="#{someBean.generateData}" value="Generate Data" immediate="true"/>
```

This way action `generateData` is invoked before any conversion or validation takes place and form data is not validated at all.

If **Generate data** needs data from the form then you can use trick described by BalusC here: [JSF 2.0 validation in actionListener or action method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5892225/jsf-2-0-validation-in-actionlistener-or-action-method)

In short, as @Jean-François suggested you can use EL expressions as value of `required` attribute. The EL expression should evaluate to `true` only when user pressed **Display Report** button. This could be done using the following expression: `#{not empty param['<fullIdOfTheDisplayReportButton>']}`. This expression checks whether id of the button belongs to parameters, which means that given button was used to submit the form.

Full example:

```
<h:form id="formId">
    <p>
        Required only for Display Report: <h:inputText id="reqForDR" required="#{not empty param['formId:displayReportButton']}" />
    </p>
    <p>
        Required for Display Report and Generate Data: <h:inputText id="reqForDRGD" required="true"/>
    </p>
    <h:commandButton id="displayReportButton" action="#{someBean.displayReport}" value="Display Report"/>
    <h:commandButton id="generateDataButton" action="#{someBean.generateData}" value="Generate Data"/>
</h:form>
```

Comment: do you know if it is possible to leave `required="false"` but to do manual data validation in the managed bean that would be requiring the field if the values of another field and A, B, or C but not requiring it if it is D ?

Comment: we have three buttons and we wanna give requirement to 2 of them through EL then how do we do that ?  ------------  like this:  required="#{not empty param['formId:displayReportButton']}"