# Trying to call ajax listener method via onevent="#{checkIfUsernameAvailable}"

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2

I have a jsf page and an input field. When the event of this input field being blurred, I would like the method checkIfUsernameAvailable() of my ManagedBean to be called. Then the image should be rendered. The problem is that that method is either never called or just not found, no matter what I do. So could someone tell me how I should do it ?
My code here doesn't work, obviously because I never call the method checkIfUsernameAvailable in my jsf. I'm sure the answer is simple but I tried so much and I just don't find it. So I removed my tried calls to this method in the code so it's without errors.

on the f: ajax i put

JSF:

```
    <h:inputText id="username" required="true" value="#{subscribeUser.user.username}">
        <f:ajax event="blur" render="usernameCheck"}"></f:ajax>
    </h:inputText>
    <h:panelGroup id="usernameCheck" >
        <h:graphicImage value="resources/images/success_indicator.png" rendered="#{subscribeUser.isIndicatorVisible.usernameSuccess}">
        </h:graphicImage>
        <h:outputText id="usernameError" value="#{subscribeUser.isIndicatorVisible.usernameSuccess}"/>
    </h:panelGroup>
```

So you see subscribeUser.isIndicatorVisible.usernameSuccess should always be false. I would like that when the input field is blurred that I'd call checkIfUserAvailable() so then it would be true and my image would then be rendered.

ManagedBean:

```
public class SubscribeUser {
    private User user;
    private Map<String, Boolean> isIndicatorVisible;

    @EJB
    Userpersistence up;

    public SubscribeUser() {
        this.user = new User();
        this.isIndicatorVisible = new HashMap<>();
        this.isIndicatorVisible.put("usernameSuccess", false);
       //...
    }

    public void checkIfUsernameAvailable() {
        this.isIndicatorVisible.replace("usernameSuccess", true);
    }
//getters & setters
}
```

Comment: Where exactly did you learn that you should be using `<f:ajax onevent>` to invoke an ajax listener method in the backing bean? Which bad book/tutorial/resource was showing you an example in that form? Then I can contact its author about this misinformation.

Comment: I think on the tutorial I read the onevent was to call a javascript function, which is correct if I ain't wrong. I just tried it to call a bean function because I just didn't find how to call the function when an event is triggered. Do you know how ? Seriously it's been a day and I just don't find how.

Comment: Which tutorial? I'd be curious why it isn't shown over there as that is usually already covered by the Hello World `<f:ajax>` usage example in a sane book/tutorial/resource.

Comment: http://www.slideshare.net/martyhall/tutorial-integrated-ajax-support-in-jsf-2-12635587 page 64. As I said it calls a JAVASCRIPT function which I believe is correct. And the tuts there are very well done.

Comment: Yes, Marty usually writes awesome tutorials. Too bad he completely overlooked `listener` on this one. I'll inform him about this sooner or later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the `listener` attribute.

```
<f:ajax event="blur" listener="#{subscribeUser.checkIfUsernameAvailable()}" render="usernameCheck"}" />
```

#### See also:

- [Java EE 7 tutorial - Sending an ajax request](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jsf-ajax004.htm#GKACE)

---

By the way, validation is usually done by a normal validator, not an action method. But I gather that you still need to learn about that part.

#### See also:

- [JSF 2.0 validation in actionListener or action method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5892225/jsf-2-0-validation-in-actionlistener-or-action-method/)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution and also for the information about validators. I'll check that out.

Comment: By the way, I find your second solution way easier on the link you gave me. Just so you know. accepted answer.

Comment: It's indeed easier for starters (particularly ones who never learned creating custom annotations via a basic Java tutorial and thus hardly understands anything in such a custom annotation). But a standard JSF Validator is also JSF centric and not reusable outside JSF, while a Bean Validation annotation is reusable outside JSF (e.g. in JPA and even "plain vanilla" Java SE).

Comment: Got it. By the way I have followed what you did and it works. Weird thing though is that in my jsf I had to put validator="#{beanValidator.validate}" while in your exemple you didn't have to put the validate method, you just put the beanValidator name. Is there a problem in my code ? Does it matter since it works ? Or maybe there is a mistake in your code... without trying to be rude since you are the one explaining me things right now.