# Server-side validation which captures each key press event with JSF

Tags: validation, jsf-2, textarea, maxlength

I have currently implemented this functionality with `onkeypress` event with pure javascript.

There is a textarea field. As soon as the user keys something, the implemented functionality shows him/her about how many characters are remaining.

Now the customer is demanding that the same to be done with validators in JSF? No Javascript.

I am confused as how will I invoke a validation method on every keypress event with JSF?

Kindly suggest something?

**EDIT:** 
I am not sure on this one,

```
<f:ajax event="keypress" listener="#{helloBean.validateLength}">
                    <h:inputTextarea value="#{helloBean.name}"></h:inputTextarea>
</f:ajax>
```

with listening method,

```
public void validateLength(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
        // stuff
    }
```

But it javscript is disabled, will this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep your JavaScript to display remaining chars. That's indeed not a real validator, but it's just an helpful indicator for which a JSF based solution would be really expensive.

To force the textarea's maxlength in client side, use the new HTML5 `maxlength` attribute on the component.

```
<... xmlns:a="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough">
...
<h:inputTextarea ... a:maxlength="1000" />
```

Hint: you can make use of it in your "Remaining chars" script to make it more generic/reusable by just letting it extract the maxlength from the HTML DOM.

Then, to validate actual maximum length in server side, just use either JSF's [`<f:validateLength>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/f/validateLength.html).

```
<h:inputTextarea ...>
    <f:validateLength maximum="1000" />
</h:inputTextarea>
```

Or BV's [`@Size`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/constraints/Size.html).

```
@Size(max=1000)
private String text;
```

Either way, you can trigger server side validation during keyup event by simply nesting `<f:ajax event="keyup">` inside the textarea.

```
<h:inputTextarea id="text" ...>
    <f:ajax event="keyup" render="m_text" />
</h:inputTextarea>
<h:message id="m_text" for="text" />
```

But as said, that's really expensive. Even if you used `<f:ajax delay>`, I'd still not recommend that and just leave it out. It has no true benefit here as the `maxlength` already restricts the maximum length in the client side.

All in all, I hope you learnt to use a normal validator in case you want to perform validation, and not try to abuse an action(listener) method for that. See also [JSF 2.0 validation in actionListener or action method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5892225/jsf-2-0-validation-in-actionlistener-or-action-method).