# infinite check for custom JSR303 annotation

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee, bean-validation

I'm trying to implement custom annotation as it is written in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5892225/jsf-2-0-validation-in-actionlistener-or-action-method), but something goes wrong. When I'm trying to persist my entity in dataBase, it gonna infinite check field with my custom annotation. I'm using wildfly 9.0.2

code:

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = User.FIND_BY_LOGIN_AND_USERNAME,query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.userName = :username and u.password = :password"),
        @NamedQuery(name = User.FIND_USER_BY_USERNAME,query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.userName = :username")
})
public class User implements Serializable{

    public static final String FIND_BY_LOGIN_AND_USERNAME = "findByLoginAndPassword";
    public static final String FIND_USER_BY_USERNAME = "findUserByUsername";

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 3,max = 64,message = "{model.User.login.message}")
    @Username
    @Column(name = "user_name",nullable = false,unique = true)
    private String userName;

    //...other fields...

    //...constructors, getters and setters...
}
```

Annotation:

```
@Constraint(validatedBy = UsernameValidator.class)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.FIELD,ElementType.METHOD,ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE})
public @interface Username {
    String message() default "Username already exists";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

Validator:

```
public class UsernameValidator implements ConstraintValidator<Username, String> {

    @Inject
    UserManager userManager;

    @Override
    public void initialize(Username constraintAnnotation) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String username, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        boolean isValid = !userManager.userExist(username);
        return isValid;
    }
}
```

UserManager:

```
@Stateless
public class UserManager {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "MySqlPU")
    EntityManager em;

    public void persist(User user){
        em.persist(user);
    }

    public User findUserByLoginAndPassword(String username, String password) {
        try {
            return em.createNamedQuery(User.FIND_BY_LOGIN_AND_USERNAME, User.class)
                    .setParameter("username",username)
                    .setParameter("password",password)
                    .getSingleResult();
        } catch (NoResultException e){
            return null;
        }
    }

    public boolean userExist(String username) {
        try {
            em.createNamedQuery(User.FIND_USER_BY_USERNAME, User.class)
                    .setParameter("username", username)
                    .getSingleResult();
        } catch (NoResultException e) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

link to [server.log](https://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/1096294?defaultVisib=Public) (snip2code)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You are saying you are getting into an infinite loop. Does that mean you have to kill the process? Or does this error appear in the logs on persist and the server continues to run?

Comment: The server stops responding , and all I can do is kill server process.

Comment: @MaxMax the JPA specification states, never invoke another db call inside a entitylistener, otherwise there would result an infinite loop. I guess this also applies to constraint validation, as they are also being executed within a jpa transaction, another db call would result into calling the same constraint validator again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem is, when i call `userExist(String username)` from my validator, it takes parent transaction and how @maress says, go to infinite loop. I fixed this problem by disableing transaction at `userExist` method. So now with this changes code will be work

```
    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
    public boolean userExist(String username) {
        try {
            em.createNamedQuery(User.FIND_USER_BY_USERNAME, User.class)
                    .setParameter("username", username)
                    .getSingleResult();
        } catch (NoResultException e) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```