# set custom message in a h:message

Tags: jsf-2

I am trying to put a custom message  in front of each of my InputText using a h:message.

My issue is that i do not find a way to set the message.

This is the HTML:

```html
<h:inputText id="_inputValue" binding="#{bean.inputtext}"/>
<h:message for="_inputValue" binding="#{bean.message}"/>
<h:commandButton value="validate" actionListener="#{bean.action}"/>
```

And in the Managed Bean i have tried different ways and still did not show the message:

Get the HtmlInput component and set its ValidatorMessage,

```html
public void action(ActionEvent event)
{
 inputtext.setValidatorMessage("ERROR");
}
```

Then as well i tried to set the message by using its clientID.

```html
public void action(ActionEvent event)
{
 //Get message id
 String messageId = message.getClientId();
  
 //Get context
 FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
  
 //Create message
 FacesMessage fmessage = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Message:", "this is an error message !");
  
 //Add message
 context.addMessage(messageId, fmessage); 
}
```

At this stage i am surprised there is not a simple way to set a message in a h:message in java after a bean validation.

i'm using JSF 2.2

**SOLUTION:**

After receiving comments, the following solution was found,

- Follow conventional JSF validation
- Using validator.

```html
<h:inputText id="_inputValue" binding="#{bean.inputtext}" validator="validatorName"/>
<h:message for="_inputValue" binding="#{bean.message}"/>
<h:commandButton value="validate" actionListener="#{bean.action}"/>
```

Then the validator will create a FacesMessage and use it in the throw declaration. throw new ValidatorException(message). The jsp message component will display the validator message since it is linked to the input text with for=_inputText.

```
@FacesValidator("validatorName")
public class MyValidator implements Validator 
{
    //[JOB OVERRIDE]
    @Override public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException 
    {
        FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage("type of validation that failed.", "detailed cause of failure.");
        message.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);

        throw new ValidatorException(message);
    }
}
```

WARNING:

- Be careful in that way the validator is not a Bean and not registered in CDI, this is why we use validator="validatorName" instead of validator="#{validatorName}".
- In case the validator is converted to a bean then remove the @FacetValidator and replace with @Named("validatorName") then use in the jsp page validator="{validatorName}".

Comment: This is because you are not doing 'bean validation' in the JSR 349/380 sence. Nor are you using a JSF validation mechanism. The way you try to (ab)use things is not common in JSF. Separation of validation and business methods (only called if all validation succeds) is what is normally done.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5892225/how-to-perform-jsf-validation-in-actionlistener-or-action-method

Comment: See `FacesContext.validationFailed()` in the second most upvoted answer in the link above. But your solution should be like the most upvoted answer.

Comment: Thank you @Kukeltje So basically it is important to follow the JSF Life Cycle, using a validator will force the application to stop during validation phase if information of inputs are not valid and automatically update related message component on the page.

Comment: @Kukeltje please answer to the question rather than comment, since i can't choose your answer as accepted there is no icon.

Comment: You can and are encouraged to answer your own question. But effectively your question is a 'duplicate' and should be marked as such and tgat is why I did not create an answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to perform JSF validation in actionListener or action method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5892225/how-to-perform-jsf-validation-in-actionlistener-or-action-method)